# Integrate a Wordpress site with Github

Tags: wordpress, git, github

I have a wordpress site that I want to work on its theme and plugins. 
The best approach is to push everything to github and update on the host, as explained here:
http://blog.g-design.net/post/60019471157/managing-and-deploying-wordpress-with-git

The problem: I don't have ssh access in the host (I use freehostia.com).
Any idea if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but if you want to push it you would need SSH access to the server. I would look into shelling out 5$+ for a host with this. Maybe look into Digital Ocean for affordable hosting.

Comment: @YoavMoran, sometimes the best option is to accept that you paid for the wrong thing, accept the loss, and move on. Hopefully it wasn't too much money since you don't even have SSH access.

Comment: @Chris you're right, but I think I found a solution anyway... Using php's shell_exec to run git actions (like clone, pull, etc.).